# How to display a particular text based on a condition in a reusable component using react and javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i want to display text based on condition in a reusable component using react and javascript.

what i am trying to do?

I have a reusable component Bar like below,

```
const Bar = ({
    label,
    indeterminate,
    showValue = !indeterminate,
    value,
    max = 100,
    ...rest
}: BarProps) => (
    <BarWrapper {...rest}>
        <Wrapper>
            <Progress
                value={value}
                max={max}
            />
                {indeterminate && <span />}
                {showValue && (
                    <span>
                        {value} <Unit>%</Unit>
                    </span>
                )}
            </Wrapper>
            {label && <Label>{label}</Label>}
        </BarWrapper>            
    );
```

I use this Bar component in couple of other components.

now there is a component "ParentComponent" that uses this Bar component. but in here it doesnt want to show value with %. instead it wants to show limit/total value. so i had added code like so,

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
    const limit = "10";
    const total= "15";
    return(
        <Bar
            showCompleted
            limit={limit}
            total={total}
        />
    );
}
```

And i have modified Bar component to display limit/total instead of showing percentage value.

```
const Bar = ({
    label,
    indeterminate,
    showCompleted = !indeterminate,
    limit,
    total,
    showValue = !indeterminate,
    value,
    max = 100,
    ...rest
}: BarProps) => (
    <BarWrapper {...rest}>
        <Wrapper>
            <Progress
                value={value}
                max={max}
            />
                {indeterminate && <span />}
                {showValue && (
                    <span>
                        {value} <Unit>%</Unit>
                    </span>
                )}
                {showCompleted && (
                    <span>{limit}/{total}
            </Wrapper>
            {label && <Label>{label}</Label>}
        </BarWrapper>            
    );
```

But the above code shows both percentage value and limit/total. how can i fix this. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: In `Parent` you're passing a prop called `showCompleted` but `Bar` accepts a prop `showCompletedValue`

Comment: Also setting the default value of a prop to the inverse of another prop (e.g. `showCompletedValue = !indeterminate`, if it even works!) is pretty strange, I could see that leading to some bugs. Why not just use the `indeterminate` prop alone to determine how the component will function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following (two versions to account for the additional condition. Not sure I understand the logic you're trying to achieve but you can modify the flags appropriately). That's the solution if you would have either `value` or `completed value` (can't be both at the same time - which I think is you're trying to achieve).

That way you don't need 2 flags (`showValue`, `showCompletedValue`) - Just one. If showCompletedValue prop is passed it displays the first one (limit/total). If it's omitted, it'll display the second one (unit %).

```
      {showCompletedValue ? (
        <span>{limit}/{total}</span>
      ) : (
        <span>{value} <Unit>%</Unit></span>
      )}

      // Another option if you need to combine 2 flags

      {(showCompletedValue && !indeterminate) ? (
        <span>{limit}/{total}</span>
      ) : (
        <span>{value} <Unit>%</Unit></span>
      )}
```

The second example is in case it has to meet both conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `showCompletedValue` prop:

```js
    const ParentComponent = () => {
        const limit = "10";
        const total= "15";
        return(
            <Bar
                showCompletedValue <--- update this prop.
                limit={limit}
                total={total}
            />
        );
    }
```